# How to find out source url of a redirected page

Tags: php, redirect

Is there a php code that can identify the source url of a redirected page?

For example: Lets say abc.com redirects to xyz.com (where abc.com is the source url and xyz.com is the redirected url)

Now I want the php code on xyz.com to identify that its being redirected from abc.com

I want to allow only those visitors to be able to view xyz.com who got redirected from abc.com

If anyone visits xyz.com from their browser, for example, then they should get a message like "Sorry u are not allowed to view this page"

Is php capable of doing this?

Comment: Try `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`

Answer (score 2):

Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].`

It returns the address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page.

For more details, refer : http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php